# Struts 1, redirect works ok but forward gives 404

Tags: java, redirect, struts, forward

In a Struts action, if I return an ActionForward with a redirect flag set to true, everything works as expected, i.e. the request ends up on the desired page. But, when I set redirect to false, it results in 404. It's important to note, I'm not redirecting directly to JSP (as in /WEB-INF/jsp/something.jsp) but to an URL (e.g items/search).

It looks like this:

```
return new ActionForward("items/search/", true);   // Works ok

return new ActionForward("items/search/", false);   // Gives 404
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `return new ActionForward("items/search/", false);` fails is simple.

By setting `redirect` to `false` (which you did in your 2nd parameter of `ActionForward`), you're effectively asking Struts to check your logical name (in your case `items/search/`) against the mapping in `ActionMapping`.

I'm quite sure that in your `struts-config.xml` there is no `<forward>` mapping for (`items/search/`) and thus, a HTTP `404`.

Read [`ActionForward` Documentation](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts/action/ActionForward.html) to understand how it works.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yup, it helps. I see now that redirecting, in this case, is my only option. Thanks.